# Как определить что была зажата комбинация клавиш?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Например **ctrl + Z + F7**

В определенном компоненте, нужно отловить факт нажатия такой комбинации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так. Написал на коленке. Не думаю, что это лучше вариантов, которые могут предложить библиотеки, но это поможет понять, как работает отлов комбинации под капотом )) Строки с комментарием `//мусор` можно удалить.

```js
let catchCombination = (() => {
  let combination = [];
  window.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    combination = [];
    document.getElementById("clicked").innerHTML = ""; //мусор
  });
  return (e, userCombination) => {
    combination.push(e.code);
    document.getElementById("clicked").innerHTML += "Зажаты " + combination.join("+") + "<br>"; //мусор
    if (combination.join("+").toLowerCase() === userCombination.toLowerCase()) {
      document.body.innerHTML += "<span style='color:green'>Комбинация поймана!<span><br>";  //тут должен быть твой код
    }
  }
})();


window.addEventListener("keydown", e => catchCombination(e, "ControlLeft+KeyZ+f7"));
```

```html
Нажми в это окно, а потом зажми control + z +f7!<br>
<div id="clicked"></div>
```

Comment: Получается в reactjs ничего встроенного нет и хорошая практика пользоваться window.addEventListener keydown и keyup?

Comment: @manking если вы хотите отлавливать нажатия где бы ни находился фокус, то это хороший вариант. Задача реакта - рисовать интерфейс, ничего встроенного в него не припоминаю.

Answer (score 1):

В объекте события обработчика onkeyup(e) есть свойстве e.ctrlKey, e.metaKey, e.shiftKey. Т.е. легко отследить комбинацию двух клавиш, одна из которых ctrl, alt, shift. Не могу представить вариант где нужно три клавиши зажать чтоб что-то тригернуть.